# Stuck at deleting a record stored in a variant datatype

Tags: vba, excel

Ok I have tried these and grasped some view on variants and I have written these code

```
Sub main()
Dim Vary As Variant
Vary = Sheet1.Range("A1:D11").Value
For i = 1 To UBound(Vary)
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(Vary)
        If Vary(i, 1) = Vary(j, 1) Then
            'I should delete the vary(j,1) element from vary 
            'in excel sheet we use selection.entirerow.delete
        End If
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

This is the sample I tried

```
 A     B     C     D 
 1    somevalues in BCD columns
 2
 3
 1
```

Now Delete the 4th row don think I'm working for unique records I'm just learning         stuff to do and while I was learning variant I am stuck at this point deleting a complete row stored in variant

I have stored `(A1:D11).value` in variant

Now how can I delete the `A6` element or row in variant so that I can avoid it while I copy the variant to some other sheet?

Can I also delete the C AND B columns in variant so that when i do transpose it wont copy the C and B columns?

I don't know what exactly a variant is  - I was thinking to take a set of range and do operations like what we do for an excel sheet then take that variant and transpose it back to sheet.

Is that the right way of thinking or did I misunderstand the use of variants?

```
`variant(k,1)=text(x)`   some array shows mismatch ? whats wrong?
```

Comment: There are many ways to use variants (and any other data type for that matter). Transposing is not something they are really used for often, although it can be done. My answer below assumes you don't need an original copy of the data you are manipulating.

Comment: Instead of deleting duplicates (which is possible, but cumbersome, as it will require reindexing and redimensioning your array), why don't you just copy the unique values to a new array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are planning on using a varray to look at cells in each row to decide if you should delete the row or not, you should loop through your varray backwards, the same way you would if you did a for loop through the cell range. Since you are starting on row 1, the variable i will always equal the row number the element was located on, so you can use that to delete the proper row.

Here's a sample (more simple than what you are trying to do, though) that will delete each row in which the cells in columns A and B are the same.

```
Sub test()

Dim varray As Variant
varray = Range("A1:B11").Value

For i = UBound(varray, 1) To 1 Step -1
    If varray(i, 1) = varray(i, 2) Then
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Notes of interest:

- UBound(varray, 1) gives the count of the rows
- UBound(varray, 2) gives the count of the columns

Comment: No i want to delete the item in variant not the cell in the sheet!

Comment: There is no easy way to delete elements from an array. Best method is create a new array and do your checks as you populate the new array, simply skipping over elements that match your criteria.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround without a second array is to introduce a deliberate error into an element you want to replace, then use SpecialCells to delete the cell after dumping the variant array back over the range. This sample introduces an error into the array position corresponding to A6 (outside the loop as its an example), then when the range is dumped to E1, the SpecialCell error removal shifts F6:H6 into E6:G6. ie

*pls save before testing - this code will overwrite E6:H11 in the first worksheet*

```
 Sub main()
    Dim Vary As Variant
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set rng1 = Sheets(1).Range("A1:D11")
    Set rng2 = rng1.Offset(0, 4)
    Vary = rng1.Value2
    For i = 1 To UBound(Vary)
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(Vary)
            'your test here
        Next j
    Next i
    Vary(6, 1) = "=(1 / 0)"
    With rng2
        .Value2 = Vary
        On Error Resume Next
        .SpecialCells(xlFormulas, xlErrors).Delete xlToLeft
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: this sample does assume there aren't any existing errors in the initial range that should be preserved on the data dump rather than deleted. This can be tested for by using Special Cells on rng1 before processing